# Use bash array as argument

Tags: arrays, bash

I have the following bash array:

```
IGNORED_DIRS=(
    "vendor"
    "node_modules"
    "bower_components"
    "tmp"
    "backup"
)
```

And I need this to be outputted in such a way:

```
tar -cpzf /var/backups/ --exclude="vendor" --exclude="node_modules" --exclude="bower_components" --exclude="tmp" --exclude="backup"
```

So far, I have tried the following:

```
for dir in ${IGNORED_DIRS[@]}
do
    EXCLUDES=$EXCLUDES" --exclude=\""$dir"\""
done
```

So that I would end up with a variable containing the exact exclude string. I thought I could simply do

```
tar -cpzf /var/backups/ $EXCLUDES
```

But that simply ignores all of the exclude flags. Has anyone got the solution for me?

Comment: It seems like I've found a solution. Substituting the `EXCLUDES` line with this `EXCLUDES=$EXCLUDES" --exclude="$dir" "` seems to fix the issue. So now there are no quotes surrounding the exclude directories anymore. Strange that his does work...

Comment: The above only works for trivial cases -- try a directory name with a space.

Comment: BTW -- all-caps variable names are used for environment variables and shell builtins with meaning to the operating system or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use; thus, using lowercase names for your own shell variables means you can't overwrite a variable with meaning to the operating system by mistake -- particularly important if you want your code to be compatible with future OS and shell releases. See [relevant spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). To summarize a solution:

```
extra_args=( )
for dir in "${IGNORED_DIRS[@]}"; do
    extra_args+=( --exclude="$dir" )
done

tar -cpz "${extra_args[@]}" -f /var/backups/
```

Comment: Awesome answer.

Comment: Or, simpler, `tar -cpz "${IGNORED_DIRS[@]/#/--exclude=}" -f /var/backups`.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying @favoretti's response, use `(..)` to collect the array and `${array[@]}` to expand the array into items, rather than joining into one string.

```
IGNORED_DIRS=(
    "vendor"
    "node_modules"
    "bower_components"
    "tmp"
    "backup"
)

for dir in "${IGNORED_DIRS[@]}"
do
    EXCLUDES=("${EXCLUDES[@]}" --exclude="$dir")
done

tar -cf /var/backup "${EXCLUDES[@]}"
```

Comment: Primarily it needs `${EXCLUDES[@]}` in the right spot in the `tar` command itself. Whether bash syntax is correct or less correct.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Learning a lot!

Comment: GNU `tar` is flexible on the point, but it goes beyond POSIX spec in that. (Though admittedly, `--exclude` is out-of-spec as well).

Comment: re: options-before-positional-arguments, see [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), guideline #9.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg, do you mind if I make the minimum necessary edits to fix the bugs?